# destructor and no constructor for abstract base class c++

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance

I searched for this, but I didn't really understand the answers.

I am completely new to C++, and what I am trying to achieve is to have an abstract class which serves as a base class for my object types so that I can store my objects in an array of pointers of type of the abstract class instead of using `void *`. Moreover, my objects share a few common member functions which could easily reduce my code base with the abstract class implementation.

However, I am confused about the constructor and destructor for the abstract class.

The abstract class doesn't really need a constructor since the parameters that could be passed in that are common to both require different things to be done with said parameter in the derived class to set the protected attributes correctly (sizing of a matrix). So, is it okay to not have a constructor? Also, since I don't have a constructor what should the *destructor* be?

I say an answer where it was to implement a virtual destructor. However, I'm not sure what this means and there was a discussion about potential memory leaks saying there wouldn't be any as long as the derived classes reimplemented the destructor. So, this does mean that I can implement a virtual decstructor and then in the derived objects say `Foo` and `Bar` I simply implement `~Foo` and `~Bar` to prevent memory leaks (assuming they're correct of course)? I wasn't confident I understood what the re-implementation in the derived classes meant exactly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Destructors

In general, when implementing abstract base classes, you have two recommended options for destructors ([source](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm)):

#### 1. Implement a public, virtual destructor

Use this when you intend to have pointers of your base class, which may point to instances of the derived class. For example:

```
class MyBase {
public:
    virtual ~MyBase() {};
};

class MyDerived : public MyBase {
public:
    virtual ~MyDerived() {};
}

std::unique_ptr<MyBase> pInstance = std::make_unique<MyDerived>();
```

By making the destructor virtual in the base class (and also in the derived class), you are ensuring that the destructor for `MyDerived` gets called at runtime. **If the destructor is non-virtual, calling `delete` on a pointer to `MyBase` will NOT call the destructor of `MyDerived`**.

#### 2. Implement a protected, non-virtual destructor

Use this in cases where you do not want to allow the user to create base-class pointers to your derived object.

```
class MyBase {
protected:
    ~MyBase() {};
};

class MyDerived : public MyBase {
public:
    ~MyDerived() {};
}

// NOT ALLOWED: std::unique_ptr tries to call protected destructor.
std::unique_ptr<MyBase> pBadInstance = std::make_unique<MyDerived>();

// Allowed: std::unique_ptr calls public MyDerived::~MyDerived()
std::unique_ptr<MyDerived> pGoodInstance = std::make_unique<MyDerived>();
```

This comes with an important caveat, however. If you have a deep inheritance hierarchy, having a non-virtual destructor means that you must enforce this rule all the way up your heirarchy. For example:

```
class MyBase {
protected:
    ~MyBase() {};
};

class MyDerived : public MyBase {
public:
    ~MyDerived() {};
}

class MyDerivedAgain : public MyDerived {
public:
    ~MyDerivedAgain() {};
}

// Uh oh! MyDerivedAgain destructor would not be called!
std::unique_ptr<MyDerived> pGoodInstance = std::make_unique<MyDerivedAgain>();
```

If you choose to go this route, you should ensure that you do not allow any of your base classes to be instantiated. **All destructors except for leaf derived classes should be protected**.

This seems a little convoluted, but it can have advantages such as avoiding vtable space, and mildly improving performance in tight loops by dodging vtable lookups at runtime (a micro-optimization at best).

### Constructors

It is perfectly okay to omit the constructor in any class as long as all variables can be default-constructed (or do not have a constructor (e.g. int)). The C++ compiler will simply create the default constructor `MyAbstractClass::MyAbstractClass() { }`. That said, it is usually preferable to create a constructor to initialize any abstract class variables:

**Okay:**

```
class MyBase {
protected:
    int _x;
    int _y;
};

class MyDerived : public MyBase {
public:
    MyDerived(int x, int y) {
       _x = x;
       _y = y;
    }
};
```

**Better:**

```
class MyBase {
public:
    MyBase(int x, int y) : _x(x), _y(y) {
    }

protected:
    int _x;
    int _y;
};

class MyDerived : public MyBase {
public:
    MyDerived(int x, int y) : MyBase(x, y) {
    }
};
```

The "Better" version with the `MyBase::MyBase(int, int)` constructor is better because it forces `_x` and `_y` to be initialized immediately, and **the compiler will check that the base class constructor is called**. By initializing base class variables in the derived constructor, you're potentially inviting disaster because you may *forget* to initialize a variable and cause all sorts of runtime problems.

#### Appendix: A Note on "Interfaces"

If you are implementing an interface class that defines a "contract", you can skip the constructor (interfaces don't have variables or implementation, constructor is not required), and use a public virtual destructor. This ensures that any class implementing the interface is going to get cleaned up when it is deleted.

```
class MyInterface {
public:
    virtual ~MyInterface() = 0;

    virtual void MyMethod() = 0;

    virtual void MyOtherMethod() = 0;
};

// Base class virtual destructors should always have an implementation,
// even when they are pure-virtual.
MyInterface::~MyInterface() { }

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

class MyImplementation : public MyInterface {
    virtual ~MyImplementation () { }

    virtual void MyMethod() { std::cout << "MyMethod()" << std::endl; }

    virtual void MyOtherMethod()  { std::cout << "MyOtherMethod()" << std::endl; }
};
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that there is also a valid use case for having protected virtual destructors in interfaces: when its life-time is managed by your implementation. Think reference-counting. You need an abstract base interface. Your interface implementations might require virtual cleanup. However, the object's life-time is controlled by the actual implementation of the Release function. You must not allow the user to delete the object 'behind your back'.

Answer (score 1):

In general *abstract classes* in c++ should provide a `virtual` destructor definition. This can be made abstract also

```
 virtual ~MyClass() = 0;

 // Define a body in any case
 MyClass::~MyClass() {}
```

An abstract class doesn't need to declare a constructor (Which can't be a pure `virtual` function BTW).

A constructor may make sense, when your abstract class isn't a plain interface (no data members).

Comment: Right, so it's the destructor being virtual I'm not sure I understand. In the implementation of the derived classes do their destructors "override" the base destructor and hence prevent memory leaks since they will be called when the derived objects go out of scope are deleted using `delete`? I'm just not understand how the destructors work here.

Comment: A virtual destructor allows a sub-class to define a destructor and ensure it will be called even if the destruction event occurs through the parent class.  Otherwise the compiler will just call the destructor for the statically defined type at the point of destruction.

Comment: @fluffy_muffin The point is that destuctors will be called virtually. So even when `delete` is called with a base (abstract) class pointer the actual types destructor will be called, and resources will be released.

Comment: @DrC Did you mean to respond to OP's comment?